# Stack using array with c

Tags: arrays, c, stack

I'm studying stack using array, and I have problem understanding codes.

```
typedef struct tagNode
{
    int Data;
} Node;

typedef struct tagArrayStack
{
    int   Capacity;
    int   Top;
    Node* Nodes;
} ArrayStack;

void  AS_CreateStack(ArrayStack** Stack, int Capacity)
{
    (*Stack)           = (ArrayStack*)malloc(sizeof(ArrayStack));
    (*Stack)->Nodes    = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)*Capacity);
    (*Stack)->Capacity = Capacity;
    (*Stack)->Top = -1;
}

void AS_Push(ArrayStack* Stack, ElementType Data)
{
    Stack->Top++;
    Stack->Nodes[Stack->Top].Data = Data;
}
```

This is the code.
I understood how it works.

But I have problem understanding this.
Stack->Nodes[Stack->Top].Data
Why the code uses '.'Data?
What is meaning and name of this?

I don't know how '.' works in C

Comment: If ElementType is a typedef of int then .Data = Data assigns the new value to the top of the stack.

Comment: If you understand `->`, then this should be trivial to you. The lone dot just accesses a member of the struct where the struct variable is not a pointer.  Put another way, `->` is just syntax sugar for a dereference *and* access, and `.` is access only.  For example, `Stack->Top` could be rewritten as `(*Stack).Top`.

Answer (score 1):

`Stack` is a pointer to an `ArrayStack`.

`Stack->Nodes` is the `Nodes` member of the `ArrayStack` that `Stack` points to. It is a pointer to a `Node`, particularly to the first `Node` in an array of `Node` elements.

`Stack->Nodes[Stack->Top]` is the element with index `Stack->Top` in that array of `Node` elements.

`Stack->Nodes[Stack->Top].Data` is the `Data` member of the `Node` element.

`Stack->Nodes[Stack->Top].Data = Data;` sets the value of the `Data` member of the `Node` element with index `Stack->Top` in the array pointed to by `Stack->Nodes` to the value of `Data`, which is a parameter of the function.

`Data` has two meanings in this statement. After the `.`, it refers to a member of a structure. By itself, on the right side of `=`, it refers to the function parameter.